# failed to swapon

Tags: swap, openwrt

OpenWrt Barrier Breaker, r44952; mikrotik rb951 2hnd.

I tried to make swap, but no success:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/swapfile bs=10k count=5
5+0 records in
5+0 records out
root@OpenWrt:~# chmod 0600 /tmp/swapfile
root@OpenWrt:~# mkswap /tmp/swapfile
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 44 KiB
no label, UUID=9358f4ae-b266-4470-b131-2eb2708b861f
root@OpenWrt:~# swapon /tmp/swapfile
block: failed to swapon /tmp/swapfile (-1)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: seems config differs a bit on openwrt:
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/fstab

Comment: Are you making a 50 kilobyte swapfile? Seems a bit too small to me...

Comment: Normally `/tmp` is mounted as `tmpfs` on OpenWRT. `tmpfs` does not support providing a swapfile.

Comment: @Thomas https://pastebin.com/k1pvi6Vh
in System Log:
user.err syslog: failed to swapon /swap1 (-1)
kern.err kernel: swapon: swapfile has holes

Comment: OpenWRT typically runs on routers with MTD storage (i.e. lower level than flash) which are set up with a read-only compressed base image (squashfs) and a and read-write overlay partition on top (previously jffs2, now it's using ubi - both are doing wear-leveling underneath). For this to work, the filesystems and underlying subsystems would need to support swap files which is far from granted. It may also be a bad idea due to the limited life of MTD blocks (and why /tmp is usually on a tmpfs). If you have a usb port though you may be able to mount a normal swap device or fs+swap file.

Answer (score 3):

From the pastebin information `/tmp` is mounted as `tmpfs` which does not support swapfiles.
Concerning your `rootfs` which is `yaffs` formatted, it seems to also not support swapfiles. Not sure why, but it might be how `yaffs` is allocating space ondisk. From the `swapon` manpage.

> The  swap  file  implementation  in  the  kernel expects to be able to write to the file directly, without the assistance of the filesystem.

One workaround might be to map the file to a loopback device and use the loopback device as the swap device. This should also work on a `tmpfs` mounted path, but doesn't make much sense as you are limiting your available RAM and hitting swap faster. However, for the sake of completeness.

First prove that `tmpfs` does not support swapfiles.

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -T /tmp/
Filesystem     Type  1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs          tmpfs   4029400 102616   3926784   3% /tmp

[root@localhost ~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/swapfile bs=1M count=100
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 0.0390268 s, 2.7 GB/s

[root@localhost ~]# mkswap /tmp/swapfile
mkswap: /tmp/swapfile: insecure permissions 0644, 0600 suggested.
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 100 MiB (104853504 bytes)
no label, UUID=bde6a47d-47f9-46b8-a492-786ab9565813

[root@localhost ~]# chmod 600 /tmp/swapfile
[root@localhost ~]# swapon /tmp/swapfile
swapon: /tmp/swapfile: swapon failed: Invalid argument
```

Then map the swapfile to a loopback device and `swapon`.

```
[root@localhost ~]# losetup /dev/loop0 /tmp/swapfile
[root@localhost ~]# swapon /dev/loop0
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1               partition   4194300 0       -2
/dev/loop0              partition   102396  0       -3
```

Comment: Don't try to bypass the limitations on which file systems can be used for swap. Those limitations exist for a good reason. Using a loopback device could mask what you are doing sufficiently that the kernel doesn't realize and let you get away with it. But you may introduce a cyclic dependency that makes your system unstable and prone to deadlock under memory pressure.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for explanation. I'ved a doubts about properties of filesystem used in my box, so it's clear now that somehow (through extX loop) possible create swap, but as mentioned by kasperd it can cause unexpected issues in further. The only one reason to create swap was insufficient of memory message during attempting to use "System" function in dialplan of asterisk pbx installed on this box.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this old thread -- but stupid question from a n00b (myself) -- how do I make this permanent in `/etc/fstab`?